# How to Connect models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, I'm trying to build a simple shop app that let the user those 2 basic shop options:

Add CUSTOMERS (name, purchased PRODUCTS from the shop, and preferred_payment (can be set to 'cash' or 'credit' only).

Add PRODUCTS to the shop (name, price, and all the CUSTOMERS who bought this)

I'm aware to has_many and belongs_to, but in this case there are many from both.
I thought about using $ 'rails g scaffold' for both of them, but what should be the best way to connect between the customers and products from your experience?

And how can I render the 'cash' / 'credit' selection as a simple dropdown menu at the new customer form?

Comment: Check out the [Active Record Associations Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: For a many- to-many, look at `has_many :through`. For a dropdown, look at the select helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `Many-to-Many` data model, You should create the relation table(join table).

If relations between models should have additional fields or extra code - You should use the [has_many :through association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Otherwise - You can use the [has_and_belongs_to_many association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

Answer (score 0):

you can generate a new model that connects the customer with his purchased products

```
rails g model cutomer_products customer:references product:references payment_method:{string or references if you has a payment method table}
```

ensure that the cutomer_product model is like this:

```
class CutomerProduct < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  has_many :customers
end
```